# How to debug NullPointerException occurred in library code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, zip

I am extracting a ZIP file in java:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(theZipFile);
  Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
    while(zipEntries.hasMoreElements()){
      ZipEntry entry = zipEntries.nextElement(); /// <---Nullpointer exception happens here
  }
```

The code execution past  `while(zipEntries.hasMoreElements())` but failed at extracting a ZipEntry.

It’s strange that `hasMoreElements` returns true, but null pointer occurs when trying to get  elements out.

The exception is from within the ZipFile class from JDK lib, which I can not see local variables in debugger, so how do I find out what is wrong with the Zip file?

Edit: 
Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:529)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:511)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:481)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Also, is there any chance that the file is being modified while you are processing it?

Comment: If you've attached a debugger to it, have you examined the value of zipEntries?  What about inspecting the elements on zipEntries?

Comment: @TedHopp stack trace is added. No, the file is not being modified during extracting.

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace? There's nothing about your code there.

Comment: @TedHopp it starts from this line in my post `ZipEntry entry = zipEntries.nextElement()`

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I did. Debugger doesn't show zipEntries's elements in a straight forward manner, say, here are the elements: 1,2,3. But yes, I will inspect all the variables of zipEntries more closely.

Comment: @Jeffrey Java 1.7.0_04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the `getZipEntry` method (as of 1.7.0_10):

```
private ZipEntry getZipEntry(String name, long jzentry) {
    ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry();
    e.flag = getEntryFlag(jzentry);  // get the flag first
    if (name != null) {
        e.name = name;
    } else {
        byte[] bname = getEntryBytes(jzentry, JZENTRY_NAME);
        if (!zc.isUTF8() && (e.flag & EFS) != 0) {
            e.name = zc.toStringUTF8(bname, bname.length);
        } else {
            e.name = zc.toString(bname, bname.length);      // Line 529
        }
    }
    /* snip */
    return e;
}
```

The only reason a `NullPointerException` would be thrown on this line would be if `e`, `zc`, or `bname` were `null`.

`e` cannot be `null` because it is clearly instantiated in this method.

`zc` cannot be `null`:

```
public ZipFile(File file, int mode, Charset charset) throws IOException
{
    /* snip */
    this.zc = ZipCoder.get(charset);
    /* snip */
}

static ZipCoder get(Charset charset) {
    return new ZipCoder(charset);
}
```

Which means that `bname` must be `null`, which is going to be pretty hard to debug. `getEntryBytes` is a `native` method:

```
private static native byte[] getEntryBytes(long jzentry, int type);
```

This is how I would proceed:

- Figure out if it's that particular zip file or all zip files. If it's that particular zip file, try remaking it.
- Update your version of Java, it's possible that there was a bug with `getEntryBytes` that was fixed
- Submit a bug report to Oracle

Comment: Ok, finally worked it out. The ZipFile has an entry which name is emtpy string!  Thanks for the detailed explanation Jeffrey!

Comment: This should get finally fixed with JDK9 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048990).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue recently and so I compared **JDK 1.6** and **1.7** related **zip source code**.

The real **reason** is **jdk 1.6** will initial **zipEntry** with **jzentry** by **constructor** *like this:*

```
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(jzentry);

ZipEntry(long jzentry) {
    initFields(jzentry);
}
```

but in **jdk 1.7** we can see it use

```
private ZipEntry getZipEntry(String name, long jzentry) {
    ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(); // it did not use jzentry initial it
```

When some **jar** file have **empty entry** it will **throw exception.**